# C++ class static struct member definition

Tags: c++

I have not found a way to initialize the class member succesfully inside the constructor and I can not figure out why.

I have a header file:

```
#pragma once

struct STATE_MOUSE {
  bool moving;
  int left_button;
  int right_button;
  int middle_button;
  bool scroll_up;
  bool scroll_down;
};

class Message {
private:
  static STATE_MOUSE state_mouse;
public:
  Message();
  ~Message();
};
```

Then I have a source file:

```
#include "message.hpp"

STATE_MOUSE Message::state_mouse = {false, 0, 0, 0, false, false};

Message::Message() {
  //Would like to initialize state_mouse here somehow.
}

Message::~Message() {

}
```

Now to the issue. This set up seems to work. However I am used to initialize members inside a constructor and I have not found a way to do that with this static struct member.

The following method does not work, could someone explain why?

```
state_mouse.moving = false;
```

Comment: `static` members are tied to the `class` as a whole, and not to individual `instances` which a `constructor` constructs.

Comment: There's exactly one instance of `Message::state_mouse`. It exists before any instance of `Message` is ever created. It's too late to initialize it in `Message` constructor.

Comment: Ah dang. Of course your answers make perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: IF you are NOT going to use static members before first object instantiation - you can create member function init() that will set proper values to all static members and call this function from constructor under http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once (since C++11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a member as `static` it will belong to the `class` with only one instance and not to the objects of the `class`, therefore you cannot initialize it inside the constructor. The constructor is a special member function which mainly exists to initialize the non `static` members of a new object.

Note that a `static` member is shared by all objects of the `class` and when an object changes it, the change can be seen from all other objects of the same `class`. If this is what do you want to achieve, then the method you shown is good.

Comment: I thank you for your answer. It is silly because that is exactly what I was going for (static being shared to all instances), but my brains at the morning could not figure out what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Static member variables are not associated with each object of the class. It is shared by all objects.

If you declare a static variable inside the class then you should define it in the cpp file, otherwise, you can get error `undefined reference`.

Note that if the static member variable is of const int type (e.g. `int`, `bool`, `char`), you can then declare and initialize the member variable directly inside the class declaration in the header file.